# Defining a global namespace with RequireJS

Tags: javascript, debugging, knockout.js, requirejs

I am new to RequireJS.  Until now, when I am developing apps, I find it very useful to create a global namespace in order to be able to test and debug my app from the chrome web inspector or the like.

For example (using knockout.js), I could define my view model somewhere in the global namspace and then just inspect it with:

```
ko.toJSON(viewModel);
```

Or Using backbone.js:

```
var App = {};
App.Model = Backbone.Model.extend({...});

//(Lets say I want to start my app with jQuery ready function)
$(function(){
    App.model = new App.Model();
});
```

And then from the console to test that my model is working properly:

```
App.model.fetch();
```

Is there a way to accomplish this while using RequireJS?

Comment: Just invoke RequireJS in the console. Try `var ko = require('knockout')`
See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8458561/interacting-with-require-js-modules-from-the-firebug-chrome-console)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I do it is that for the modules for which it makes sense I purposely leak *some* values into the global space *only* if the code detects that it is running in a test environment.